# Surface mesh problem

Tags: mesh

I have downloaded a file that has some problems with the mesh. The meshes are not connected correctly, is it possible to connect only the visible part of the meshes? [image]

Comment: Hello, you could select one of your mesh with L then Ctrl F > Intersect (Boolean) but it won't give a good topology at the end, you'll need to correct it

Comment: Unfortunately, L then Ctrl F > Intersect (Boolean) doesn't work. The command delete one piece. I add the file in the post

Comment: Once you've booleaned you need to choose Union in the Operator Box (bottom left of your 3D view)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select one of your mesh with L then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Intersect (Boolean)* but it won't give a good topology at the end, you'll need to correct afterwards:

[image]

Once you've booleaned you need to choose Union in the *Operator Box* (bottom left of your 3D view):

[image]